# Cloudformation error: Template validation error: Template error: Fn::Select cannot select nonexistent value at index 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In parameters, I am using this

```
envGOSBasicAuthentication:
    Description: "xyz"
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: "username, password"
```

In configuration template, I am using below code:

```
OptionSettings:
         - Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment'
           OptionName: PASSWORD
           Value: !Select [2, !Ref envGOSBasicAuthentication]
```

But I am getting error: Template validation error: Template error: Fn::Select cannot select nonexistent value at index 2

Why I am getting this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index starts with 0.

From the AWS documentation: `This must be a value from zero to N-1, where N represents the number of elements in the array.` (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-select.html).

Therefore, try the following instead to get the password from `envGOSBasicAuthentication`.

```
OptionSettings:
- Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment'
  OptionName: PASSWORD
  Value: !Select [1, !Ref envGOSBasicAuthentication]
```